# Normal Internet surfing, without being redirect

Tags: internet

Disclaimer: I'm new in the smartphone world.

So, I  have my new smartphone (LG5), I open the browser and I would like to surf internet as I do from my laptop.

I go to google, search a site, for example a newspaper page, I click and... I'm automatically redirect to a page starting with and "m" like m.normal.site.addres which is the page for mobile devices, and which is often a pay-service.

How can I see the normal web page without being redirect?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome for Android, you select "Request desktop site" from the menu in the browser.

I don't know if your phone ships with Chrome as the default browser or something LG have cooked up, so the option might be named differently, but there should be an equivalent.

Most sites will respect this, but you might find that if a site is redirecting you to push you to a pay service, they have another way of redirecting you anyway.

Comment: Thanks! If my default browser does not have this choice, how can I install a clean version of chrome?

Comment: You can [install it from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome).

Comment: Worth noting that dolphin browser, boat browser, opera etc are great alternatives to Chrome (I do NOT like Chrome, long story) and have this option also!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your smartphone does not support Chrome browser. By the way, you can do the thing suggested by @Dan Hulme with almost every "custom" browser on the Play Store.
Opera is a good choice (you must consider the lightest one) but Firefox, expecially in the last updates, is another good choice.

If I remember well, the stock andoird browsers has this option too: try to check in the settings!